# Deploying Rails to Render: PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, deployment, render, pg

I have a problem with deploying my Rails back-end app to Render. I am currently running with a PostgreSQL database and am encountering the same error every time:

[the error coming from render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skcIg.png)

When I go back to my app, I check to see if the server is running using pg_lsclusters--and it is! It is online. I start and end, and have restarted as well, all using sudo.

[cluster running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSSSL.png)

I also check the directory that the error is pointing to. Inside there is the .s.PGSQL.5432 file:

[the .s.PGSQL.5432 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xup0b.png)

This is my render-build.sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o errexit
bundle install
#clean
rm -rf public
#build
npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
#migrate
bundle exec rake db:migrate
#postbuild
cp -a client/build/. public/
```

This is my database.yml:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  url: <%= ENV['DBURI'] %>
```

This is puma.rb:

```
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 4 }
preload_app!
plugin :tmp_restart
```

I really don't know what else to do. This is my first time attempting to deploy on Render.

Thus far I have tried:

- Uninstalling/reinstalling RMV, then installing Rbenv to manage Ruby
- Uninstall & reinstall Ruby
- Uninstall & reinstalling PG
- Purging PG and all its servers, recreating the db
- Reinitiating the cluster, purging all other clusters
- Restarting system

None of these have resolved the issue. I can db:migrate but the issue always continues to occur when attempting to build in Render for deployment.